# How to manually mock a module (ioredis) with a constructor

Tags: jestjs

I'm following the manual mock example from the Jest docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html)

I'm attempting to extend this example to my own project and my manual mock of ioredis (**mocks**/ioredis.js).  I'm trying to mock out the ioredis client hget with my own (so I can return test values) but I'm having trouble due to the fact I need to create a redis client with a constructor `let client = Redis.new` before I have access to the mocked `client.hget`.

Here is my manual mock of ioredis:

```js
// __mocks__/ioredis.js
/* eslint-env node */
'use strict';

const IORedis = jest.genMockFromModule('ioredis');

const hget = jest.fn()
  .mockImplementationOnce(cb => cb(null, '123'))
  .mockImplementationOnce(cb => cb(null, '456'));

// this approach does not work, I'm wondering if I have to create the client
IORedis.hget = hget;  
module.exports = IORedis;
```

When I'm testing I can see that ioredis is indeed getting mocked and if I do a `console.log(this.client.hget)` in my actual module right before use I see this:

```js
{ [Function]
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function],
      mockReset: [Function],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
      mockReturnValue: [Function],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
      mockImplementation: [Function],
      mockReturnThis: [Function],
      mockRestore: [Function],
      _protoImpl:
       { [Function]
         _isMockFunction: true,
         getMockImplementation: [Function],
         mock: [Getter/Setter],
         mockClear: [Function],
         mockReset: [Function],
         mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
         mockReturnValue: [Function],
         mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
         mockImplementation: [Function],
         mockReturnThis: [Function],
         mockRestore: [Function] } }
```

In my actual tests nothing is being returned and if I remove my manual mock `hget` function I see the same thing in the console log.  I'm assuming this problem would exist for any module that would require a constructor (as opposed to the "fs" example) so the answer is probably a generic one.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the solution was pretty simple. In my ioredis manual mock I just had to do this:

// Original answer

```
IORedis.prototype.hget = jest.genMockFn();
IORedis.prototype.hget.mockImplementation(function (key, link) {
    // return whatever I want here
});

module.exports = IORedis;
```

// Latest versions of Jest

```
const IORedis = jest.genMockFromModule("ioredis");
IORedis.prototype.hget = jest.fn((key, link) => {
        // return whatever I want here
    });



module.exports = IORedis;
```

Comment: For those who stopped in this question, newest versions of jest don't use this jest.genMockFn() any more. replace it with jest.fn();

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment @MarcosBergamo , much appreciated

Comment: Can we update the answer with the latest code? This is still a top response when googling :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sinon as your stubbing library. You can stub the ioredis.

```
import { createSandbox } from 'sinon';  
import * as ioredis from 'ioredis';

beforeAll(() => {
  const sandbox = createSandbox();

  sandbox.stub(ioredis.prototype, 'connect').returns(Promise.resolve());
  sandbox.stub(ioredis.prototype, 'sendCommand').returns(Promise.resolve());
})

afterAll(() => {
  sandbox.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither answer above worked. The file I'm testing has a global instance of a class (call it Foo) and I want to mock the instance's methods.

foo.js

```
export class Foo {
  method(param) {
    console.log(`Foo.method called with ${param}`);
  }
}
```

handler.js

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

const foo = new Foo(); // Static instance at global scope

export const handler = (param) => {
  foo.method(param);
};
```

handler.test.js

```
import { Foo } from './foo';
import { handler } from './handler';

jest.mock('./foo', () => {
  const Foo = jest.fn();
  Foo.prototype = { method: jest.fn() };
  return { Foo };
});

describe('handler', () => {
  it('calls foo.method with given param', async () => {
    Foo.prototype.method.mockClear();
    handler('hello');
    expect(Foo.prototype.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
  });
});
```

Assigning to Foo.prototype at global scope, as in @josh803316's answer, didn't work for me; I had to do the assignment within the mock of './foo' module.

BTW, none of these problems occur if the instance of Foo is created inside the handler function - the fact it's a global instance makes the usual tricks not work, apparently because of the order things get done within jest.

Hope this helps someone. (Probably me, in about 12 months when I've forgotten how I did this.)

Comment: Thanks @Roofus, Jest has changed a lot since I posted my answer so it's not surprising it might be different now. I appreciate you posting this for me and others who might come across the same challenges we faced.